# Tidesdk - Launch desktop tidesdk application at windows startup

Tags: html, desktop, startup, tidesdk

I have a desktop application created with TideSDK, I need this application to launch at windows startup, but can't find how, I mean, when the application is installed or launched by first time, I want it to setup to launch with windows startup. If someone has worked on it, it will be very helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not a function. Please create a github todo for a feature request.

Comment: I was just looking into this myself. I haven't gotten to it yet, but as it's not native functionality, I thought I might be able to do it by executing a system command to update the registry (Windows) or run an Applescript (OSX). Is there any reason this wouldn't work from a TideSDK perspective?

Comment: Usually stuff like this has to be added to different sections (Mac it's the launchd, Windows it's the Registry, Linux it's a couple of things).

Comment: In my case, I just need it for windows, and thought something simple, just like creting a shortcut and send it to the startup directory on windows, but couldn't find the respective constant on Ti for this system path. (My native lang is spanish, if there is something not too clear by mi eng, I'm sorry)